# Display all the lines and line number of the given file

Tags: php

I have following code of lines to find the line and line number. I have html table with search bar at the top. Firstly I want to display all the lines and its line number in this html table. Then based on the search filter, the associated line number and line number is to be displayed in that table. I am not being able to show all the lines at the moment. But when i pass any value from the search bar it is showing the filtered result.

When my $str is "Adobe" it is generating the the line number containing the that word and also the whole line containing that given word. Now what I am looking for is display all the lines and line number in a table and filter the line based on the search.

Can anybody help me with following lines how can I show all the lines and its line number of the given file.

```
<?php include 'file.php';?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names..">
        <input type="button" name="view" value="View" class="btn-View">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table>
        <?php foreach($arr as $ar){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="8%"><?php echo $ar['line_number'];?></td>
                <td width="92%"><?php echo $ar['line'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

file.php

```
$file = "file/file.txt";
$str = "Adobe";
$arr = count_line_no($file, $str);

function count_line_no($file, $str)
{
    $arr_lines = array();
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $count = 0;
        $arr = array();
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            $count+=1;
            if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
                $arr_lines['line'] = $line;
                $arr_lines['line_number'] = $count;
                array_push($arr, $arr_lines);
            }
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: you want to display both filtered and whole lines ?

Comment: display all the lines in the table. which later to be displayed on filter

Comment: Your code seems to work fine - what errors are you getting? or what additional behaviour do you need? do you just need help to display the table? what have you tried?

Comment: outside this condition `if (strpos($line, $str) !== false)` add new array and store your data in it;

Comment: @hassan where to add that line

Comment: @Theo Yes I need help to display all the lines in the table. And $str will contain the search value which I later pass from search field. I have to write pure php code. Cant use bootstrap or other third party

Comment: Your updated code works for me, I see a table, with the matched lines - what do you see when you run?

Comment: @Theo lets say for the first time there is empty $str instead of $str = "Adobe", In this case I need to display all the lines of that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findLines($file,$str,$start=1,$limit=false){
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $lineNo= 0;
        $matches=0;
        $arr = array();
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            $lineNo++;

            if (empty($str) || strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
                $matches++;
                //continue loop if we haven't reached our start point
                if($matches<$start){
                    continue;
                }
                $arr_lines=[];
                $arr_lines['line'] = $line;
                $arr_lines['line_number'] = $lineNo;
                $arr[] = ['line'=>$line,'line_number'=>$lineNo];
            }
            //stop when we have read the maximum number of lines
            if($limit!==false && $matches>=($start+$limit)){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

This supports blank search and pagination:

```
$arr = findLines($file, $str);
$arr = findLines($file, $str,10,10);
```

to work out from a page number:

```
$page=2;
$perPage=10;
$start = ($perPage)*$page-1;
$arr = findLines($file, $str,$start,$perPage);
```

Comment: Great untill you find the file has 100,000 lines and this method blows your memory limit!

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I plan to display with pagination. You can suggest me better solution

Comment: @Shyam I have updated my answer to support all your requirements, you should  really update your question to include these - I would make suggested edits myself, but there are a number of outstanding edits in the queue - you should review these and accept, reject, or make your own edits to be clear that you need to support empty search text and pagination

Comment: @RiggsFolly my answer previously used the file function to read the whole file, on the basis they wanted to support empty search strings this would be fine as if reading the entire file were to hit memory limits then an empty search would not work. With the additional requirement of pagination I agree this solution would not be suitable and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Theo Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$file = "file/file.txt";
$str = "Adobe";
$arr = count_line_no($file, $str);
print_r($arr);
function count_line_no($file, $str)
{
    $arr_lines = array();
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $count = 0;
        $arr = array();
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            $count+=1;
            if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
                $arr_lines[]=array('line' => $line,"line_number"=>$count);
            }
        }
    }

    return $arr_lines;
}
```

**Output format:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [line] => Adobe

            [line_number] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [line] => Adobe

            [line_number] => 11
        )

)
```

Comment: I want to display all the lines at the beginning. Your code is giving me the same result that my code is giving

Comment: I have updated my question. I have to display all the lines to my table and later filter it

Comment: @Shyam If you iterate on the given result you will be able to get the data in your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

I did by adding these lines.

```
if(empty($str)){
    $arr_lines[]=array('line' => $line,"line_number"=>$count);
}else{
    if (strpos($line, $str) !== false) {
        $arr_lines[]=array('line' => $line,"line_number"=>$count);
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way?